# efficient lookup where key is a set of key-value pairs pointing to an object

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, garbage-collection, jvm

I seek for some inspirations. my problem is how to pool an object identified by key-value pairs. I am working on JVM and don't want to create garbage when creating those objects in runtime - that's why an idea of pooling.

so lets give some example - user can provide identifiers like `(A(1) B(4))`, `(A(1) B(2) C('foo') E(0))`, `(B(4) A(1))`, `(A(0))`, etc.. - for each of those set of pairs I would like to get unique reference to object created earlier. mind that `(A(1) B(4))` and `(B(4) A(1))` should point to exactly the same ref - of course I can sort by keys and then perform calculation.

of course I could create a map in runtime as a key and keep a `Map<Map<K,V>, T>` but this is not really efficient when we talk about X thousands of lookup per second.

I was thinking about hashing those input pairs to get unique id - but somehow I have to prove that hashing function will have no collisions when number or variety of k-v increase in runtime. I expect to have no more than 1M of unique k-v pairs, so computing an id would be the best solution and map that id to an object - but I need function that will calculate such id.

maybe some smart graph structure could be a solution, the only trouble I have is that not only keys create a graph but also values of those keys.

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Whatever key type you come up with, creating an instance of it for the lookup implies creating garbage.

Comment: that's the thing - maybe we could get away with not creating a key type. I am leaning towards calculating some id

Comment: You can easily implement a dedicated lookup structure for one concrete key type, but a general purpose map for arbitrarily structured keys boils down to reinventing an object system. But there’s no reason why yours should be better than the one, the JVM already has.

Answer (score 0):

I ve solve this particular problem with having a instance of Key builder per thread, key builder holds an array of objects - this array is of known size as we have strictly defined keys (in example it was A,B,C, etc - so we know ordinal of that key).

I dont allocate anything for each request execution, we reuse builder's to set  key-values in the array and once that is done I can use the key to find or create object identified by those K-V. also this approach solves problem of order, as it doesnt matter whether somebody identified object by `(A(1) B(4))` or `(B(4) A(1))` - to follow the example.

I could use Map instead of Objects[], but at least implementation of java.util.HashMap allocates lots of node objects, and I will clear such map for every request! If you use a Map that caches nodes - then maybe this is a way to go.